# How to filter content resolver query results in android? Passing selection parameter still doesn't work

Tags: android, sql, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to filer out city names and return matching cities based on the selection parameter being passed.

However the query call still returns all the rows.  Even tried putting in a fake city name that doesn't already exist in the database and it still spits out the same original rows.

```
public void addLocation(String cityName){
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getResolver().query(
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + 
            " = " + cityName,
            null,
            null);
```

I've read the Android docs over and over, [ContentResolver Query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#update%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29), and passing the selection parameter in doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
public final Cursor query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the provider you're using is `androidx.core.content.FileProvider` (according to what you've declared in your manifest), the `selection`, `selectionArgs` and `sortOrder` parameters of `FileProvider.query` are... *ignored* in AndroidX's implementation !

See the v1.2.0 source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-support-lib-19.1.0/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java) (line 409)

The only solution I found is to filter and sort the results *post-query, in your own code*. 
And yeah, that's kinda sad...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the value in the selection parameter, put it in selectionArgs.

```
public void addLocation(String cityName){
    String[] args = { cityName };
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getResolver().query(
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + 
            " = ?",
            args,
            null);
```

Comment: Already tried that and it doesn't work. Even if passing selectionArgs is the preferred method, I still want to understand why the query I currently have is not working.

Comment: Do you have access to the provider source code? In that case you can check if and how the parameters are used. Perhaps you need to use a different URI?